# Exiting out of a program through a menu option

Tags: python, menu, exit

I need to say first and foremost, I am just learning Python.

I am making a simple python program that has a menu option for exiting the program by using a function I called exit.  I have tried making the exit function just call break, but I am getting an error when the exit function is called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry for not posting code earlier....

```
def exit():
    break


evade = evade_fw()

# Main program running dialogue
def main():  # menu goes here
    opt_list = [xsl_file,
                basic_loud_scan,
                fw_main,
                exit
                ]
```

Comment: error message? what have you tried?

Comment: show us your code first

Comment: post your code ...

Comment: added code, sorry for not posting earlier, wasn't able to get a lot of sleep last night :(

Answer (score 1):

Just forget about your own `exit()` function. You can simply do:

```
from sys import exit
```

And the `exit()` function from `sys` module will do the job.
It's also worth to know what happens under the hood. Function `sys.exit()` actually throws a special exception. You can do it as well explicitly and without importing anything:

```
raise SystemExit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` is for breaking out of `for` or `while` loops, but it must be called from within the loop. I'm guessing that you expect the `break` to break out of your program's main event loop from an event handler, and that is not going to work because, as aforementioned, the `break` must be within the loop itself.

Instead your exit function can clean up any resources, e.g. open files, database connections, etc. then call `[sys.exit()][1]` which will cause the Python interpreter to terminate. You can optionally pass a status code to `sys.exit()` which will be the system exit status available to shell scripts and batch files.

```
import sys

def exit():
    # clean up resources
    sys.exit()    # defaults to status 0 == success
```